# Uncheck the checkboxlist after submitting using knockout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

In my checkbox list control the user selects few options and submits them and those selected values will be sent to the server after clicking the save button.

Im using knockout observable array to bind the checkbox options from the database and also after the user selecting the checkbox options also to send those values to the server side im using an observable array.

I have 2 issues in this:

1) When the user clicks the save button im saving those values to database but still the checkbox options are being checked and i want to uncheck those after the clicks the save button.

2) As im binding the options for checkbox list from the database, it takes 3-4 seconds time to get the values from the database and bind them, but before binding the options a single checkbox is being showed and dont want it to be displayes.

```
 <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'choiceTmpl', foreach: viewModel.choices, templateOptions: { selections: viewModel.selectedChoices } }"></ul>

<script id="choiceTmpl" type="text/html">
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: viewModel.selectedChoices" />
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</li>
</script>
```

this is how my view model looks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var viewModel = {
choices: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],

selectedChoices: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

button click event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easiest with knockout if you go all the way and don't mix any jQuery in there (except 
for AJAX requests and your custom bindings).

Here is what I would change

- Use `viewModel.selectedOptions.removeAll` after your submit has finished. **This should clear the checkboxes like you asked**.
- Add `data-bind="visible: true" style="display: none;"` to your top element being bound. This will keep the template from showing up until knockout is done binding. This should avoid your "single checkbox showing" prolem. If it doesn't I will revise this answer with a different solution since I may not be understanding you are populating the values of the checkboxes.
- Use `checkedValue` to tell the checkbox what the value is rather than `attr: { value...`. This is a knockout 3.0 binding, but it is well worth the upgrade if you are still using knockout 2.0. It allows for using arbitrary objects to match against for the checked binding, not just strings. *Note: Your `attr: { value...` should actually work since you are using just strings.*
- Have knockout handle the form submission, not a jQuery click event. This is also not necessary to get your thing to work.

Here is some revised code:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: choices">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedChoices, checkedValue: $data" />
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<button type="button" data-bind="click: submit">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        choices: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
        selectedChoices: ko.observableArray(),
        submit: function () {
            //your submit code here
            //read your selectedChoices, call $.ajax, etc

            //when all is finished, do the following:
            viewModel.selectedChoices.removeAll(); //this clears the checkboxes
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

The idea is that you don't ever have to tell your javsacript about what is going on in the DOM. `ko.applybindings` should take care of all of that. No need to bind a click event manually to your submit button.

If you must bind to your submit button using jQuery `.click(function () {...`, just place the `selectedChoices.removeAll` inside the `done` of your ajax request whereever it is being executed from.

Comment: thank you sir, you solved my problem and yes i will improve my code as per your suggestion and vl post here if any issue..once again a big thank you.